# Why getting WindowsPrinciple in AuthorisationManager in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, claims-based-identity

I am trying to implement claim based security in web application. I have a class like.

```
public class AuthorisationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        //if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAdmin())
        //    return true;
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        var action = context.Action.First().Value;
        return context.Principal.HasClaim(resource, action);
    }
    public override void LoadCustomConfiguration(System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodelist)
    {
        base.LoadCustomConfiguration(nodelist);
    }
}
```

and I have CustomPrinciple like

```
 public class CustomPrinciple  : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public CustomPrinciple(IIdentity identity)
        : base(identity)
    {
    }
}
```

Its always returning false because `context.Principal` is WindowsPrinciple. I tried to set it in Globas.asax.cs like

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            PermissionManager mgr = new PermissionManager();
            mgr.CheckUserAccess("", "");
            mgr.LoadPermissionModel("XYZ");

            HttpContext.Current.User = mgr.LoadPermissionModel("ABC");
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
        }
    }
```

How can I change it so that I can get the `CustomPrinciple` in `CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)`

Thanks

Comment: I guess you have "<authorization mode="Windows"> in your web.config instead of "Forms" or "None" (both should work with claims based auth).

Comment: you are right. I am able to get `GenericPrinciple` now in AuthorizationManager but still I need to get `CustomPrinciple`  in that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am able to get it now. Thanks for this. You can add it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The suggested answer to be accepted):

I guess you have `<authorization mode="Windows">` in your web.config instead of `Forms` or `None` (both should work with claims based auth).

Comment: I am using a WCF service and have set authorizationMode to 'None' and still getting a WindowsPrincipal the second time CheckAccess is called. (Yes it's called with a ClaimsPrincipal the first time - where the principal matches my incomingPrincipal from my ClaimsAuthenticationManager, but with a WindowsPrincipal the second time).